# JavaScript to PHP variable value pass error (document.write command is not working)

Tags: javascript, php, document.write

After sending the country name "US" in JavaScript to PHP code, I will try to receive the results of PHP's work back to JavaScript and use them.
To do this I used the below code.

$ctryNm_php_temp = "document.write(ctryNm);";

As a result, it seemed that the value 'US' of the ctryNm variable was well transfered to php code.
The cryNm value and $SQL value printed on the screen contain 'US'.

However, the results of the SQL query were returned to an empty value, so we checked.
The IF statement shows that ctryNm and 'US' are different values.
(The output on the screen shows the same value and data type as string.)
I printed $result_obj and found no value.

echo and console.log command result for checking:

[image: echo and console.log command result for checking]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ctryNm = "US";
    </script>

    <?php
        $ctryNm_php_temp = "<script language='javascript'>document.write(ctryNm);</script>";
        $ctryNm_php = $ctryNm_php_temp;
        echo $ctryNm_php . "<br><br>";
        echo "--------------" . "<br>";
        echo gettype($ctryNm_php) . "<br>";
        if ($ctryNm_php == 'US') {
            echo "Same" . "<br>";
        } elseif ($ctryNm_php != 'US') {
            echo "Different" . "<br>";
        }

        $conn = new mysqli("...", "...", "...");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, '...');
        mysqli_query($conn, "set names utf8");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM acst_covid_who WHERE country_code = '$ctryNm_php'";
        echo $sql . "<br>";
        $result_obj = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "result_obj :" . $result_obj . "<br>";
        $date_adjust = 0;
        $latestDate_trend = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_obj)) {
            if ((int)$row['confirmed_new'] !== 0) {
                $latestDate_trend = $row['date'];
                $date_adjust = 1;
            } elseif ((int)$row['confirmed_new'] === 0) {
                $latestDate_yester_trend = strtotime($row['date'] . "-1 days");
                $latestDate_trend = date("Y-m-d", $latestDate_yester_trend);
                $date_adjust = 0;
            };
        };

        $result_obj = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $total_rows_trend = mysqli_num_rows($result_obj) - $date_adjust;
        $arr_trend = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_obj)) {
            array_push($arr_trend, $row);
        }
        echo $total_rows_trend;
        echo json_encode($latestDate_trend);
    ?>

    <script>
        var latestDate_js_trend = <?php echo json_encode($latestDate_trend) ?>;
        var arr_js_trend = <?php echo json_encode($arr_trend) ?>;
        var arr_length_trend = <?php echo $total_rows_trend ?>;

        console.log(latestDate_js_trend);
        console.log(arr_js_trend);
        console.log(arr_length_trend);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: PHP runs on server. JavaScript runs on the client. They do not interact with each other. The PHP code is done running before the JavaScript executes. You can not do what you are trying to do. You need to use a form submission, Ajax. or fetch to talk between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Actually, I tried the way you said it, but it didn't work out.
JAVASCRIPT to PHP was able to transfer values, but it was not possible to reverse the results that PHP performed with the values sent by JAVASCRIPT to JAVASCRIPT.
If you could give us some advice and examples of this method, please.

Answer (score 0):

this sadly does not work like this.
PHP code is executed first on the server, so before the website is even shown in the browser. The order you write it does not matter.

The process is like this:

1. You type the address in the browser and it asks the server for the page.
2. The server literally runs an app called php, that reads what you wrote in the code, reads only what is between `<?php` and `?>`, nothing else (technically the first one can be `<?=`)
3. When it is done, the server sends the page to browser
4. The browser reads html and fires JavaScript, long after PHP was already changed.

This is simplified but show why your code will not work.

Comment: I clearly understood why not. Thank you. I'll have to try again in a different way, considering the principle you told me.